# How to write React with the new syntax?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Basic question. I am trying to re-write my old `React Skeleton` project in the new way but I am having issues making it work. What am I doing wrong?

Old method

```
var React = require('react');
var ListItem = require('./ListItem.jsx')

//Component
var ingredients = [{ "id": 1, "text": "Ham"}, { "id": 2, "text": "Cheese"}, { "id": 3, "text": "Bread"},]

//Component
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var listItems = ingredients.map(function(item) {
      return <ListItem key = {item.id} ingredient = {item.text} />
    });
    return ( <ul>{listItems}</ul> );
  }
});

module.exports = List;
```

New method

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem.jsx';

const ingredients = [{ "id": 1, "text": "Ham"}, { "id": 2, "text": "Cheese"}, { "id": 3, "text": "Bread"}];

class List extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const listItems = ingredients.map((item) =>
      <ListItem key = {item.id} ingredient = {item.text} />
    );

    return (
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    );
  }
};
```

I am new to react so forgive me if my mistakes are basic. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exaxtly does not work?

Comment: what's not working ?

Comment: Do you need to `export default List`?

Comment: Error: Parsing file /Volumes/Backup/Playground/JS/__udemy_react/react-skeleton-update/src/components/List.jsx: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (21:0)

Comment: I am also trying to understand if what I wrote is correct.

Comment: This might help - https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/103

Comment: Thank for this. It was missing a preset from babelify, however now I have a new issue. I am getting this error on the console `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object` Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stateless component, as you've presented here, would not be written as a class. Instead, you are more likely to see it written as a [functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components).

```
import React from 'react'

import ListItem from './ListItem'

const ingredients =
  [{ "id": 1, "text": "Ham"}, { "id": 2, "text": "Cheese"}, { "id": 3, "text": "Bread"}]

const List = props =>
  <ul>{ingredients.map (item =>
    <ListItem key={item.id} ingredient={item.text} />)}</ul>

export default List
```

Perhaps even more likely you are going to see data like `ingredients` passed as a property, instead of accessing a free variable like you have

Click **Run code snippet** below to see the demo code in action

```js
const ingredients =
  [{ "id": 1, "text": "Ham"}, { "id": 2, "text": "Cheese"}, { "id": 3, "text": "Bread"}]

const List = props =>
  <ul>{props.ingredients.map (item =>
    <ListItem key={item.id} ingredient={item.text} />)}</ul>

const ListItem = props =>
  <li>{props.ingredient}</li>
  
ReactDOM.render(<List ingredients={ingredients} />, document.querySelector('#main'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Of course now `List` and `ListItem` can be made more generic. Why limit ourselves to using them only on ingredients?

```js
const ingredients =
  [{ "id": 1, "text": "Ham"}, { "id": 2, "text": "Cheese"}, { "id": 3, "text": "Bread"}]

const List = ({items,each}) =>
  <ul>{items.map((item,key) =>
    <ListItem key={key} item={each(item)} />)}</ul>

const ListItem = ({item}) =>
  <li>{item}</li>
 
const Ingredient = ({text}) =>
  <div className="ingredient">{text}</div>
  
ReactDOM.render(<List items={ingredients} each={Ingredient} />, document.querySelector('#main'))
```

```css
.ingredient {
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am going to try.

Comment: doing on your way, if I decided creating the two components in separated  files, how would I export it? `export default ComponentName` ?

Comment: How you organize the modules is up to you. If I use a *default* export, then that's generally the only component that will be written in that file. Other categorically similar components live side-by-side in the same file and are exported en masse - in this kind of arrangement, I will *not* specify a default export.

Comment: very interesting. Thank you for your help.